# .htaccess для сокращалки url'ов

Tags: .htaccess, url

Здравствуйте.
Пишу простой сокращатель url'ов, которые формируются в виде http://mysite.com/ujGh4oi5ug
Вопрос:
Как в .htaccess настроить перенаправление с http://mysite.com/ujGh4oi5ug на http://mysite.com/index.php?ujGh4oi5ug
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index.php?$1 [L, QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```